# Comparing matching column data from 2 different tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql

I have 2 tables

TABLE1 and TABLE2 in access.

both tables have a column named 'Email Address'.

What I want to do is write a query which creates a new table, which holds
only the matching email address's that were found from both tables via 
their columns

ie.

```
===========================================================================
TABLE1           
Email Address    
d@hotmail.com    
===========================================================================
TABLE2         
Email Address  
d@hotmail.com   
===========================================================================
NEWTABLE3
Email Address  
d@hotmail.com 
===========================================================================
```

I'm using access 2010. 
I understand I'll probably need a join on both tables via that column
name then someway to compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT Table1.[EMAIL ADDRESS] INTO NewTable
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[EMAIL ADDRESS] = Table1.[EMAIL ADDRESS];
```